# material-ui chips - drag and drop support

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am would like to use [material-ui chips](https://material-ui.com/demos/chips/) in my react-app.
The problem is that I would like to move the chips with drag and drop. This functionality is not supported by `material ui`. Is there a workaround / extension to get chips draggable? <!--

If there is no other way, I would change to another library. Does anyone know one?
Thank you

**//EDIT-Good solution**

You can make any component draggable with [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd)

Comment: is there any example for combining material chip with react-beautiful-dnd?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Draggable component from material UI:

```
<Draggable><Chip label="your chip" /></Draggable>
```

See full example: https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/#draggable-dialog

Comment: Good direction. But now I have the behavior that components are superimposed. Unfortunately, I could not find anything in the documentation to disable this behavior. So maybe another good tip?

Comment: It does not have any api like this .. but i got it from your link .. it's `react-draggable` ..

Comment: Draggable isn't enough to implement intelligent sorting once you've dragged