# how to make table rows draggable using for react for functional component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draggable

I am new with react, and have been working with it using functional components only. I need to use draggable feature for table rows (To change the order of rows in a table by dragging them.)

Is there any (`material ui` is prefered) package for `draggable table row` like this http://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/, but instead of list here, I need `draggable table`. Or is there any reliable version of `draggable table` for react

Also I found some others [this](https://autodesk.github.io/react-base-table/examples/draggable-rows) and [this](https://garden.zendesk.com/react-components/tables/#!/Draggable). But both of them are using class and I am not able to understatnd how to convert them to functional components. Please Help.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811842/material-ui-chips-drag-and-drop-support

Comment: @Mateen not really. Do you know any other row draggable package for tables?

Comment: Sorry I don't know.

Comment: I found one, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/ . But I am finding it difficult to implement onclicks and rerendering table after changes in some cells. Trying...